# Can somebody help me with removing # from the #contact in the url http://localhost/example/#contact

Tags: php, html

Can somebody help me with removing `#` from the `#contact` in the URL    `http://localhost/example/#contact?`

with : `http://localhost/example/contact`

```
<div class="navMenu" id="nav-menu">
    <ul class="navList">
        <li class="navItem"><a href="#home" >Home</a></li>
        <li class="navItem"><a href="#about" >About</a></li>
        <li class="navItem"><a href="#contact" >Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `#` from `href` and it will get removed from URL as well

Comment: No buddy it will throw too much error because I have not created pages for home, about, and contact.

Comment: I have created a page index.php and in the same page I have created Three sections with Id home, about, and contact. Therefore to reach that section on current page You have to use ' # '.

Comment: In this situation, Can you suggest me the solution to remove ' # '. You might also learn something new because removing ' .php ' extention with .htaccess is not a big deal. This is big deal because it's solution is not provided anywhere. Good Luck !!

Comment: Please check this :  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/#smooth-scroll-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

add just this script

```
$("a").attr("href",$("a").attr("href").replace(/#/, ""));
```